# Subtract one year, if it is not current year - hive

Tags: date, hive

I am working on hive. I have few data including `dateofbirth` column but the requirement is like need to reduce `year` by `1` if it not the current year. I am stucked up here. please suggest me to solve this in Hive.

Answer (score 1):

YEAR function and add_months will help you. Hope this helps. Thanks.

```
select IF(YEAR(dateofbirth)=YEAR(current_date), dateofbirth , cast(add_months(dateofbirth, -12) as date)) from t

Result:
dateofbirth     minus 1 yr
2016-12-28      2015-12-28
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of add_months functions. It works also with negative numbers in order to subtract months.: select add_months('2009-05-31', -1) ; --> 2009-04-30. Note that the date is un european date format yyyy-MM-dd